# How to display a PDF file in a Vue 3 Component?

Tags: pdf, vuejs3

I am finding it difficult to display a PDF file inside a component in Vue 3 Laravel application. I tried using the PDFObject package, but I get a message:

```
This browser does not support inline PDFs
```

Any package or techniques that any one has used, please let me know.

Thanks for your help